# MySQL Split date range into separate records

Tags: mysql, date-range

I need to split one date record into a several date records (dynamically, depending on a date range that overlaps) like this in MySQL:

input data:

```
level    |start_time              |end_time

1         2018-12-24 09:00:00     2018-12-25 09:00:00
```

Output result should look like:

```
level    |start_time              |end_time
1         2018-12-24 09:00:00      2018-12-25 00:00:00
1         2018-12-25 00:00:00      2018-12-25 09:00:00
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please explain the logic.

Comment: From the above, I take it you mean when a start and end time have different days, you wish to adjust them into multiple records, one for each day (setting the times to midnight for the break).

Would a three day record (start 2018-12-24 end 2018-12-26 be equal to 3 records, or still two?)

Are you wanting to update the records in your database, or is this just a select query you're after?

Comment: @Sam - if period spans across 3 dates - it should be 3 records created from one and yes - I'm looking for a simple select here.

Comment: Your problem is solvable using a number generator. Here are some example solutions (it is not same as your question, but should give you an idea):  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53458694/2469308 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53418090/2469308

Comment: thanks everyone for your input. I was able to find out a simple solution on my own. topic can be closed now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initiate your sql code like this.  It's a long shot but I hope it get you started somewhere.

```
select tx.col1
FROM
(  (
      SELECT start_time as col1 from  t1
  )
  UNION 
  (
      SELECT end_time as col1 from  t1
   )
) as tx
```

Comment: thanks for your input. I managed to tackle solution with a different approach on my own.